# Some consumers in Kafka Consumer Group not receiving messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka consumer group containing 5 consumers, each of which is deployed on different servers.
While producing the values on the topic, only 3 consumers out of 5 are receiving messages, while other 2 consumers are not receiving messages at all. I have restarted each of the faulty consumers, but still no success.
Consumer configuration values are as below.

```
auto.commit.interval.ms = 101
auto.offset.reset = earliest
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
check.crcs = true
client.id = 
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
enable.auto.commit = true
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = temp_topic_group1
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = null
internal.leave.group.on.close = true
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 2
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 305000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Comment: Good to refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998127/kafka-consumer-receiving-messages-inconsistently

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Kafka Consumer not receiving messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760866/simple-kafka-consumer-not-receiving-messages)

Comment: Thanks for reply! If so is the case, then how is it working fine in case of other 3 servers. Initially only 2 consumers were receiving messages, but then I restarted the third server, and then it also started receiving messages.

Comment: How many partitions are there for the topic? Number of partitions should be >= number of Consumers in the same Consumer group.

Comment: there are 5 partitions

Comment: @acsh, Do all consumers have same configuration as in the question or the have different one?

Comment: all of them are having identical configuration

Comment: @acsh, did you fix this issue? if yes, how you fix it? I am also facing same issue. Thank you.